# Issue filtering out certain event logs from output

Tags: html, powershell

So I've coded a little script that sends me the last 24 hours event logs for my Servers in a nice HTML Email to save me having to log on to each Server, etc. It works well except some of our applications produce loads of events that I want to filter out.

I have managed to use a where statement to filter out one however when I try to add another event ID to it fails to work as expected.

Snippet of my code below:

```
$ApplicationEventsReport = @()
$ApplicationEvents = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $computer -LogName Application -EntryType Error,Warning -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) | where {$_.EventID -ne 1530}

foreach ($event in $ApplicationEvents) {
        $row = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
                TimeGenerated = $event.TimeGenerated
                EntryType = $event.EntryType
                Source = $event.Source
                Message = $event.Message
                EventID = $event.InstanceID
        }
        $ApplicationEventsReport += $row
}

$ApplicationEventsReport = $ApplicationEventsReport | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

You'll notice at the end of the get-eventlog line there is the where section that -ne's the ID if that makes sense.

I've tried to add another in the following ways:

```
where {$_.EventID -ne 1530 -or $_.EventID -ne 3221229571}

where {($_.EventID -ne 1530) -or ($_.EventID -ne 3221229571)}

where {$_.EventID -ne 1530} | where {$_.EventID -ne 3221229571}

where {$_.EventID -ne 1530} -or {$_.EventID -ne 3221229571}
```

However none of these work they either ignore it completely or still only process the first one (the 1530)...

Any thoughts on why this fails, they all appear to work if I run the line locally on my machine it only seems to fall over once I place back in the script?

Comment: What if you leave only `{$_.EventID -ne 3221229571}` - will at work as a single condition itself?

Comment: That longer number looks like an InstanceID. `where {$_.EventID -ne 1530 -and $_.InstanceID -ne 3221229571}` work? Depending on what you are trying to filter out creating an array and using `-notcontains` might be preferential. Using `-or` might be messing with you if those values are not for the same event entry and could prevent them from being excluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see a couple of potential issues. If we have a look at a few event from my local computer.

```
EventID InstanceId Message                                                                                                                                   
------- ---------- -------                                                                                                                                   
   1202 2147484850 Security policies were propagated with warning....                                                                                        
      0          0 The description for Event ID '0' in Source 'gupdate' cannot be found.  The local computer may not have the necessary registry informati...
   1001       1001 Fault bucket , type 0...                                                                                                                  
   1001       1001 Fault bucket , type 0...                                                                                                                  
   1003 1073742827 The Software Protection service has completed licensing status check....                                                                  
   1202 2147484850 Security policies were propagated with warning....                                                                                        
     32 1073741856 The store ...                                        
     32 1073741856 The store   ....
```

I see numbers like yours but for the **instanceID**. So a simple change would be something like this.

```
Where-Object {$_.EventID -ne 1530 -and $_.InstanceID -ne 3221229571}
```

You should be use `-and` since using -or could cause an issue if the to be filtered records only match one of the criteria.

If you have a lot of records to filter then you could store the values in arrays for use in your `Where` clauses.

```
$eventsToIgnore = "1004","1500","10001"
$instanceIDsToIgnore = "3221229571","2147484850"

#.... blah blah... other stuff

Where-Object {$eventsToIgnore -notcontains $_.EventID -and $instanceIDsToIgnore -notcontains $_.InstanceID}
```

Comment: Perfect Matt, I used the arrays method and piped it through to the where and bingo! I guess I was getting confused as well with -or and -and, in my head -and would mean it needs to have both values but I guess its exclude so it is to exclude either... It's been a long day! Thanks again